# Можно ли скриптом заменить цвет внутри всех таблиц стилей?

Tags: javascript

Имеем внутри таблиц стилей множество элементов, которым задан цвет или фон с определенным значением. Например, #f00. Можно ли при нажатии на кнопку сделать подмену этого HEX-кода другим? При этом не имея классов элементов, к которым они прописаны в CSS?

Comment: а зачем это может понадобиться на клиенте? почему просто не подгрузить другой файл со стилем, например?

Comment: Выбрать для себя цветовую схему и сохранить данные в localStorage. Что-то вроде персонализации для пользователей, если это можно сделать без излишнего гемороя.

Comment: Геморрой будет излишним. Вариантов много, и все они не очень хорошие. Если у вас spa то можно заморочиться, а вот если отдельные страницы, то будет хорошая нагрузка на клиенте.

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт заменит все `background-color` цвет которых равен `rgb(255,0,0)` (`#ff0000`) на `rgb(0,255,0)`.

Не работает на стилях загруженных с чужих доменов.

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets // все стили (dom объекты стилей <link>, <style>)
for( var i = 0; i < sheets.length;i++ ){
   var all_rules = sheets[i].cssRules // все правила (не работает если стили с чужого домена)
   for( var j = 0; j < all_rules.length; j++ ){
       var rule = all_rules[j];
       // селектор можно проверить через rule.selectorText

       //отбросим все не таблицы (просто для примера).
       if( rule.selectorText !== 'table' ) continue;

       //ff переводит цвета из hex в rgb (не смотрел в хроме)
       if( rule.style['background-color'] === 'rgb(255,0,0)' ) 
           rule.style['background-color'] = 'rgb(0,255,0)';
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Завтра потестирую и отпишусь о результате.